# How to plot a parameterized curve with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a function `f: R -> R^2` like `f(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))`, but I don't see how to do it.

```
f(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))
plot f(x) # doesn't work
splot f(x) # doesn't work either and is probably not what I want
```

Is there a way to plot such a function in gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check `help parametric`, `help special-filenames`, `help sampling` and this: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/param.html.

Here are two approaches:

**Script:**

```
### parametric curves
reset session

fx(t) = cos(t)
fy(t) = sin(t)

set size ratio -1
set xrange[-1.1:1.1]
set yrange[-1.1:1.1]

set multiplot layout 1,2
    set parametric
    plot [t=0:2*pi] fx(t), fy(t) w l lc "red"
    unset parametric

    plot sample [t=0:2*pi] '+' u (fx(t)):(fy(t)) w l lc "blue"
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]